# How to get sum of sql column value client-side?

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp, jstl

Server-Side I have this table called `product`:

```
id | prod_name | prod_price | description | points
```

As shown above, each product has point value kinda like Starbucks where each coffee you buy gives you a sticker and once you complete a card, you get free coffee. I'm using the same concept for my store.

Every product bought give the user its points. Of course the value of the points works according to the price. The higher the merrier for him.

How can I show him the total of points he has accumulated based on the products he put in his basket/cart? Every time he puts a product in his basket, the sum needs to upgrade dynamically. I would prefer `JSTL` or `SQL` as a solution to minimize the amount of `JS`, but i'm fairly opened to the latter.

So this is basket.jsp:

```
<div class="pointsContainer">
    My Reward Points: ( <c:out value="${points + points}" />  )
</div>

<div class='block'> 
    <c:if test="${!empty basket && basket.numberOfItems != 0}">
        <h3 class='boardRowHeader'>My Products</h3> 
    </c:if>
    <c:forEach var="basketItem" items="${basket.items}" varStatus="iter">
    <c:set var="product" value="${basketItem.product}"/>
        <div class="cart_row">
            <div class="cart_img"><a href="viewProduct?${product.id}">
                <img class="image" alt="" src="${initParam.productGalleryImagePath}${product.id} (1).jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="cart_nme"><a class="category_links" href="viewProduct?${product.id}">${product.name}</a></div>
            <div class="cart_price">$${product.price}</div>
            <div class="cart_update">
                ${product.points} points
            </div>
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already on Java EE 7 / Servlet 3.1 / EL 3.0 (Tomcat 8, WildFly 8, GlassFish 4, etc), then just use [Stream operations and Lambda](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el004.htm) in EL. This works just on Java 6/7 too and does not per se require Java 8.

E.g.

```html
<c:forEach items="${basket.items}" var="basketItem">
    <c:set var="product" value="${basketItem.product}"/>
    <div class="cart_row">
        <div class="cart_update">${product.points} points</div>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
<div class="totalPoints">
   Total Points: ${basket.items.stream().map(item -> item.product.points).sum()}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use counter variable in your for-loop like this:

```
<div class="pointsContainer">
    My Reward Points: ( <c:out value="${points + points}" />  )
</div>

<div class='block'>
    <c:if test="${!empty basket && basket.numberOfItems != 0}">
        <h3 class='boardRowHeader'>My Products</h3>
    </c:if>
    <c:forEach var="basketItem" items="${basket.items}" varStatus="iter">
    <c:set var="totalPoints" value="0"/>
    <c:set var="product" value="${basketItem.product}"/>
        <div class="cart_row">
            <div class="cart_img"><a href="viewProduct?${product.id}">
                <img class="image" alt="" src="${initParam.productGalleryImagePath}${product.id} (1).jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="cart_nme"><a class="category_links" href="viewProduct?${product.id}">${product.name}</a></div>
            <div class="cart_price">$${product.price}</div>
            <div class="cart_update">
                ${product.points} points
            </div>
        </div>
        <c:set var="totalPoints" value=" ${totalPoints + product.points}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</div>

<div class="totalPoints">
   Total Points: <c:out value="${totalPoints}" />
</div>
```